# Create CLOB from long string using JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, clob

I have the following query:

```
select id from table1 where some_func(?) = 1;
```

where `some_func` is a function which allows its arguments to be either VARCHAR2 or CLOB, and `?` is some string, which could be really long.

I am trying to use the following code to bind variables:

```
stmt.setObject(i+1, obj);
```

but in case of `string.length()` > 4000 I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
```

for an obvious reason: the VARCHAR2 size limit is 4000 characters.

I then tried to use the following code:

```
if(obj instanceof String && ((String) obj).length() >= 4000) {
  String s = (String) obj;
  StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
  stmt.setClob(i+1, stringReader, s.length());
} else {
  stmt.setObject(i+1, obj);
}
```

which gave a different error:

```
ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value
```

The last idea I tried was to create a CLOB using `oracle.sql.CLOB.createTemporary()` method but it failed because of the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException:
  org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper 
  cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

What am I doing wrong? Are there any other possibilities to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the setCharacterStream method in PreparedStatement?

Comment: Yes, please look at my previous answer (a_horse_with_no_name was a bit faster)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The CLOB could be created in a simple manner:

```
if(obj instanceof String && ((String) obj).length() >= 4000) {
    Clob clob = connection.createClob();
    clob.setString(1, (String) obj);
    stmt.setClob(i+1, clob);
}
```

Then these clobs should be freed of course.

Comment: When to use setString instead of setCharacterStream?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience setCharacterStream() is much more reliable than setClob()

```
String s = (String) obj;
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(s);
stmt.setCharacterStream(i + 1, stringReader , s.length());
```

and it works without the need to create CLOB objects

Comment: Unluckily, I get the same error as with strings: `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested`

Comment: What datatype is the underlying column? I have no problem using this with CLOB columns.

Comment: This is just a parameter for the some_func function, which is 3rd-party software, so I do know only that it accepts CLOB or varchar2 as parameter.

Comment: You might be getting the VARCHAR2 version of the function.  Use named parameters to make sure you're getting the one you expect.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to use named parameters with such a function so I tried to create a CLOB and succeeded. See my answer if you want to.

Comment: A named parameter works like this: `select id from table1 where some_func(parameter_name => ?) = 1;`

Comment: Thank you, +1. You mentioned from your experience, ' setCharacterStream() is much more reliable than setClob()'. But can you please share more details on what you experienced or why you prefer it?

Comment: @prash: some drivers don't implement `setClob()` at all (at least not 3 years ago when I wrote this. And some drivers would work correctly using `setClob()`. I don't recall the details. Maybe today's drivers are better regarding this.

Comment: Thanks for revisiting and replying to my query. Ok, I understand your point.

Comment: Why to use setCharacterStream instead of setString?